# S-Shaped Learning Curve

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network

For a model that I'm currently testing, I get an S-Shaped curve when plotting the MAE over consecutive epochs, as shown in the image below.

[image: MAE curve]

I was curious if this indicates a problem with the model or if this is normal. Most learning curves that I've seen follow a logarithmic shape, with a steep decrease in error rates at the beginning of training, which gradually flattens out. I should mention that occasionally the model does not converge at all, and I have to restart training.

The model is a regression model built to perform predictions over timeseries data, with a few 1D convolution layers at top, and some dense layers at the bottom. The output is a continuous value.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not really a problem, but I guess something unwanted. The generalisation only begins after 10 epochs and can be considered slow.

This S-shaped curve is due to a transition phase between two learning regimes. The first should be some kind of memorisation or basic inference (like a constant or random returned value). To my knowledge, it's pretty seldom. I have only seen it in two cases (I don't exclude it can happen other how):

- Over-parametrised network plus small|wide(#features) dataset (maybe like [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05553)?)
- LLMs Grokking: see [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.02177), [[3]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10343) and especially [[4]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.05217)

I hope this answer can help you, don't hesitate to challenge it anyway.